# Interpolating 3D WRF Data against a 2D array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, interpolation, weather

I've been working on a python script that I'm using for my WRF model research and I'm having some difficulty with interpolation routines. In my case, I'm trying to plot a specific field, however, using a sweeping pressure level across the board, especially for the lower levels (1000, 850) usually result in extreme maxima or nan values when dealing with the mountain regions as they are below the ground level.

So, my idea was to write a script that detects the pressure level of the ground (Easily done with the following):

```
pb = ncFile.variables['PB'][0][0]
p = ncFile.variables['P'][0][0]
sfcPres = pb + p
```

Which results in a 2D array surface containing the ground pressure, and then establish two other fields containing pressures 50hPa and 100hPa respectively above these:

```
medLevel = sfcPres - 50
topLevel = sfcPres - 100
```

From here I wanted to give the three arrays: sfcPres, medLevel, and topLevel to an interpolation function as the height parameter to interpolate the data set at each of the lat,lon pairs to the respective lat,lon pairs of the three arrays.

My problem is that all of the interpolation routines that I have used such far only allow for interpolation to a singular value for the pressure level, which as I stated above result in the problem of edge extremes.

I would like to be able to do something on the order of [this function](http://wrf-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_api/generated/wrf.interplevel.html#wrf.interplevel) where the desiredlevel argument can take that 2D array and perform the interpolation on the 3D data set (Arrays of [Z, lat, lon]) at each point within that 2D array.

Does anyone know of a simple way to do so that does not involve using loops as the data sets are rather large, and I need to compute mean values of the function using 8 combined sets for about 60 files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this and it does involve using loops. I have my own WRF routine that linearly interpolates a 4D variable field to constant height surfaces that I specify. I trust you should be able to modify this function for pressure surfaces. I have been working though WRF data troubles myself.

```
def linear_height(var,surface): #defaults to .5km to 20.5km with .5 km intervals
    '''
    Requirements:
    import numpy as np

    This function will take in a variable and the corrosponding height surface of the model to
    then interpolate to constant height surfaces from 500m to 20km at 500m intervals.
    The interpolation to the new height surfaces is linear and occurs from the lowest level x,y point
    to the top level x,y point.

    The output variable will have the same units as the input variable but will have a different shape
    Assuming that height is the second column of the array, this will be the only length to change
    example: linear_height(Temperature, Height_surfaces)

    '''
    ######################################
    #Edit to change the levels of the interpolated height coordinates
    new_height = np.arange(500,20500,500) # 1km to 20 km
    ######################################
    new_surf = np.empty((var.shape[0],new_height.shape[0],var.shape[2],var.shape[3]))

    for TIM in np.arange(var.shape[0]):
        for IDX, VAL in np.ndenumerate(var[0][0]):
            new_val = np.interp(new_height,surface[TIM,:,IDX[0],IDX[1]],var[TIM,:,IDX[0],IDX[1]],left=np.nan, right=np.nan)
            new_surf[TIM,:,IDX[0],IDX[1]]=new_val[:]
    return new_surf
```

Comment: I see, that's disappointing. I've got a 4km 24 member ensemble simulation over a good majority of CONUS that I need to generate ensemble means of an instability parameter which uses five variables that require interpolation using this method. My test script on a single WRFOUT file was still running after 24 hours so unfortunately it looks like I'm out of luck for this particular plot.

Thanks anyways!